# FSX and ESD SDK, what is the difference?

Tags: simulation

I am interested in SimConnect for FSX. I find the [SimConnect SDK docu under ESP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc526983.aspx) - is this the same SimConnect as featured under the FSX SDK?

If there is a difference, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://www.fsdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=175529

Basically it is the same, find the details in the answer above.

Comment: For people finding this post since MSFS2020 got released, the SimConnect documentation lives over on https://docs.flightsimulator.com/html/Programming_Tools/SimConnect/SimConnect_SDK.htm